# Unable to refresh readonly entity in the cache

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I want to define a JPA entity as read-only using the entity annotation to prevent updates.  But since it's value occasional changes by another update to the database, I want to be able to refresh the cache's object.

However, when I attempt to execute the following code, an IllegalArgumentException: 'Can not refresh not managed object' gets thrown on the call to refresh():

```
public <T> T refresh(EntityManager em, Class<T> className, Long primaryKey) {
    T t = em.find(className, primaryKey);
    LOGGER.debug("object={}, contained={}", t, em.contains(t));
    em.refresh(t);
    return t;
}
```

As it turns out, even though I retrieved the entity object from the EntityManager, the debug statement indicates that the entity is not contained by the EntityManager and therefore cannot be refreshed.

Is there a way to refresh a read-only entity in the cache?

---

Note that if I remove the @Readonly attribute from the entity class definition, the EntityManager.refresh call successfully syncs the object to its database value.  I'm using the built-in eclipselink caching mechanism.

Comment: how exactly you are pushing the object into cache, whatis the implementation for cache

Comment: please post the classes where refresh is in and from where it is called

Comment: Your ReadOnlyEntity has to be managed by the EntityManager when calling refresh(). Your EntityManager tells you in the Debug-Message that it does not contain the Entity. When the EntityManager gets a Transaction-Commit it flushes the cache. It seems that em.find() ends the transaction immediatly and the entity is detached

Comment: Try adding a refresh query hint to a property map to pass to the initial find call, em.find(className,primaryKey, properties) with properties described here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching#How_to_refresh_the_cache

Comment: Updated original post to answer these questions